# How to keep office LAN private from public WLAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I handle the network at a small business; it's not my primary job but one that I am in charge of. My boss owns a house next to the office that he use as a general meeting area and as a guest house for friends and family. The house is close enough to the office that our office WLAN covers most of the house.

Our office router (Cisco Linksys EA4500) supports a "guest" network, which is okay for people that pop in for meetings, but not so great for family and friends that may stay for several days or a week. The guest profile times out, and they have to reconnect. I have no way to set the timeout period for the guest profile. But mainly, there are several "dead spots" in the wifi coverage in the house.

There is an Ethernet cable running from the office to the house that is not currently being used. Optimally, I would just use the spare Ethernet cable to setup a seperate WLAN in the house. But I don't know how to do it so that the guests cannot get access to our office network.

I would like to leave the office network hardware and configuration unchanged if at all possible.

I am open to purchasing something, and even flashing it with DD-WRT if needed. I just need a configuration that keeps the office network private.

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about network engineering/administration

Comment: @Adnan Why not flag the post for migration then?

Comment: @ekaj We can't flag to migrate to [NetworkEngineering.SE](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) as it's still a beta site.

Comment: The Network Engineering guys didn't like it either since the question was related to a SOHO router. They recommended I move it to SuperUser... StackExchange is getting complicated <sigh>

Comment: @Adnan I meant SuperUser. This would fit in their guidelines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to add some new configuration rules, I do not see any other way. Best thing to do is to make a separate VLAN and subnet for the house. You then simply do not route between the house and office network. If I were you I'd ask your ISP for an additional IP to NAT the house network with (but you can do it with your office network's IP if you are comfortable with that).

Comment: Questions: 
1) The EA4500 does not support VLAN's that I can tell. Are you saying that I would have to do that with a DD-WRT router?
2) If we can get a 2nd IP, would I just connect a switch to the cable modem, then connection each router to the switch?

Comment: Ah didn't see you can't have separate VLANs. If you have two routers then this is not really necessary an issue. You can just configure one for the first IP and the other one for the second.

Comment: I like the idea of using separate IP's. It's like $10/mo from the ISP to get another one. Our IP's are not static though, so I couldn't hard code an IP into the router. I think using the switch will be what we need to do, (we have several spare switches around the office) I just need to get another wireless router.